# Extract GIF frames retaining base canvas size + offsets

Tags: image, imagemagick, extract, gif, offset

I am trying to extract GIF frames using ImageMagik `convert` command. The GIF images are optimized to only overlay animated changes (I believe they call it mipmap) and this is ideal for my extraction due to performance limitations. If I use `-coalesce` I lose the optimization since I'm using the GIF frames in a spritesheet so I need to extract it as is but when I do extract it with the standard `convert xxx.gif xxx.png` the animation frames are extracted without offsets and the canvas sizes are different to the base image (0).

[image]

I need all the images extracted to match the first frame with retained offsets from the GIF meta-data. I have no idea how to accomplish this in ImageMagik and want to know if this is possible?

Then if I get them matching sizes with offsets applied I can add them to the sprite sheet easily.

Would appreciate all the help I can get! Thanks.

[image]

Pro challenge! Do you accept?! :)

Comment: How about posting the animated GIF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extract to GIF, rather than PNG, it seems fine:

```
convert animated.gif frame%d.gif

identify frame*
frame0.gif GIF 307x465 307x465+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 61.8KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame1.gif[1] GIF 278x372 307x465+16+61 8-bit sRGB 256c 19.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame10.gif[2] GIF 278x371 307x465+17+62 8-bit sRGB 256c 17.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame11.gif[3] GIF 278x370 307x465+17+63 8-bit sRGB 256c 17.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame12.gif[4] GIF 275x371 307x465+20+62 8-bit sRGB 256c 17.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame13.gif[5] GIF 276x370 307x465+19+63 8-bit sRGB 256c 17.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
frame14.gif[6] GIF 275x369 307x465+19+64 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.8KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

If you want to overlay these onto a blank canvas, you can do it something like this. I haven't thought about it too much and there may be an easier way, but for now...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extract individual frames
convert animated.gif frame%d.gif

# Make a blank canvas same size as original
convert -size 307x465 xc:none canvas.gif
i=0
for f in frame*; do
   geom=$(identify -format "%X%Y" $f)
   convert canvas.gif $f -geometry $geom -composite +repage g_$i.gif
   ((i++))
done
```

Or maybe you mean you want all the frames in their correct relative positions but one after the other in a long sequence in a single file?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract individual frames
convert animated.gif frame%d.gif

# Make a blank canvas same size as original
convert -size 307x465 xc:none canvas.gif

# Paste individual frames onto blank canvas and append frames into long sequence
for f in frame*; do
   geom=$(identify -format "%X%Y" $f)
   convert canvas.gif $f -geometry $geom -composite +repage miff:-
done | convert - +append sequence.gif
```

[image]

Comment: What I want to do is have it extract into a canvas that matches `frame0.gif GIF 307x465` dimensions (307x465) with the offsets applied per frame. Is there a command to automate this algorithm?


So it would end up being 0+0 for all the frames in the sprite sheet since I don't want to manually apply each offset in my application (would be a lot of work haha). Thanks for the help!

Comment: When I try the second method you proposed it just creates a blank canvas.gif image and all the frames remain the same size as before. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe you want all the frames on a single canvas? See updated answer.

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Thank you so much for this help! It is working perfectly :) you are a life saver. Even providing extended help beyond my initial question. You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: My pleasure - glad to be of assistance!